# Selecting div text by text in <span>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to select div text on the page by special span text. For example, I have:

```
<div>
  <span> Org name: </span>
   "corp. org name"
 </div>
```

So, I want to select `corp. org name` by searching all finds by text in span tags. `Org name:`

Comment: Could you provide the URL you're experimenting??

Comment: https://reestr.minsvyaz.ru/reestr/61245/ i am selecting names of organisations from the right column

Comment: What gives `print(soup.find('div').find('span').text)`

Comment: i have plnety of divs, so in my case it will be just a first 'div' with span. But i need exact span  with Org name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can't speak Russian. So, I can't verify if that is what you want or not.

I have made what I think you want, which to search for `org name:` to return `Corp. org name:`. The following function does exactly that and it returns a dictionary of `org name` as key and `corp org name` as value. Here it is:

```
def scrape(url):
    page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    #find all divs on the right side
    lst = soup.find_all('div', {"style": "margin-bottom: 16px;"})
    #the output dictioary
    corpNames = {}
    for idx, link in enumerate(lst):
        #get the text inside <span> which is the key
        key = link.find('span').get_text()
        if key:
            value = link.get_text()
            value = re.sub(key, "", value)
            value = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", value) #reduce white spaces
            corpNames[key] = value.strip()
    return corpNames
```

And this is how to use it:

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> url = "https://reestr.minsvyaz.ru/reestr/61245/"
>>> d = scrape(url)
>>> print(d)
{'Альтернативные наименования:': 'ЭПС "Система ГАРАНТ"', 'Класс ПО:': 'Информационные системы для решения специфических отраслевых задач, Поисковые системы, Прикладное программное обеспечение общего назначения, Офисные приложения, Лингвистическое программное обеспечение', 'Сайт производителя:': 'http://www.aero.garant.ru', 'Дата регистрации:': '20 Февраля 2016', 'Рег. номер ПО:': '6', 'Дата решения уполномоченного органа:': '20 Февраля 2016', 'Решение уполномоченного органа:': 'Приказ Минкомсвязи России от 20.02.2016 №63', 'Ссылка на приказ Минкомсвязи:': 'Приказ'}
```